# "So That" vs. "Such That"

Tags: soft-question, terminology

In definitions and exercises, I notice that "so that" and "such that" are seemingly used interchangeably. Are they in fact interchangeable, or is one more appropriate for a specific context?

*Note:* $\mathrm{Dom}\,(f)$ means the domain of $f$.

Example 1:

> Suppose that a function $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ and $f(c) > 0$. Prove that there is a $\delta > 0$ $\color{red}{\text{so that}}$ for all $x \in \mathrm{Dom}\,(f)$, $$ |x-c| \le \delta \ \Rightarrow \ f(x) \ge \frac{f(c)}{2}  $$

Example 2:

> A function $f(x)$ is continuous at a point $c \in \mathrm{Dom}\,(f)$ if and only if for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ $\color{red}{\text{such that}}$ for all $x \in \mathrm{Dom}\,(f)$:  $$ |x - c| \le \delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x) - f(c)| \le \varepsilon $$

Comment: Thank you @MarkDominus, "terminology" is a more appropriate tag

Comment: To me in this case “such that” seems more appropriate. “So that” to me is to be used when something is to be constructed or demonstrated to have a property, while “such that” means that we assume a property of an object. But I'm not a native English speaker, so I might be wrong. :)

Comment: http://www.jmilne.org/math/words.html

Comment: @Andrew: a very nice link, thank you! :)

Comment: Agreed, thank you @Andrew

Comment: There is an English stack exchange site. Perhaps that would be a better fit to this question.

Comment: I thought about that @DavidMitra but then I considered that mathematicians were the most accustomed to the "pidgin English" (to quote Andrew's source) that mathematics is written in.

Comment: @David: I’ve answered some questions there; based on my experience, it would probably be suggested that this question would be better asked here.

Comment: @Andrew: the link is indeed nice, but its author unfortunately blunders by arguing that "$a(n)\neq0$ for all $n$" should mean "some $a(n)$ is nonzero" instead of "all $a(n)$ are nonzero", which is ridiculous.

Comment: Dear @MarcvanLeeuwen, I hadn't actually looked that far when I posted the link. But, I think his point is that the statement is ambiguous. Does it mean that $a(n)$ is never zero, or that $a(n)$ is not *always* zero?

Comment: Dear @Andrew: In my view there is no ambiguity: formulas _always_ bind more tightly than text, so the "for all $n$" can only apply to all of "$a(n)\neq0$". Assuming that, as Milne suggests, one could take the negation bar out of the formula and make it say "NOT ($a(n)=0$ for all $n$)" is what I consider ridiculous. Note that one can't even do this is you pronounce "$\neq$" as "is unequal to".

Answer (score 4):

Clauses that begin "such that" function as adjectives; they modify nouns. Clauses that begin "so that" function as adverbs; they modify verbs (or adjectives or other adverbs).

In both of the examples in the question, "such that" is the correct choice, because the clause modifies $\delta$.

In certain cases, either choice can be justified because the difference in meaning ends up not mattering. For example, in "Choose $n$ such that $2n+1$ is prime," the "such that" clause is about $n$. In "Choose $n$ so that $2n+1$ is prime," the "so that" clause is about the action of choosing; it says to do the choosing in a manner that ensures that $2n+1$ is prime. The overall effect of the two options is the same. (Personally, I'd prefer "such that" in this example.)

Comment: 'So that', 'unless', 'only if' and the like all suffer from colloquial usages that frequently aren't strictly logical/correct. However, once I slow down, to my ear, 'so that' (which is synonymous with 'in order that') introduces a clause that furnishes *nonrestrictive, optional* information (about consequence); as such, I think that "choose $n$ so that $n+1$ is even" is *technically* incoherent, even as I have [caught myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/332017/2) writing 'so that' when I actually mean 'such that'.

Answer (score 2):

‘***so that***’

- introduces a clause that (inessentially) *conveys the intended consequence* of the preceding instruction/assertion
- logical sense: **therefore**
- means ‘in order that’

1. Let $f(x)=x^3+3x^2−10x$ **so that** $f(1)=−6$ and $f(2)=0.$

---

‘***such that***’

- introduces a (modifying) clause that *stipulates a restriction*
- logical sense: **and**
- variously means ‘in which’, ‘satisfying’, ‘for which’

1. $S$ is the set of reals **such that** each, for some natural $k,$ equals $2k.$
2. Every complex $z$ is **such that** $|z|$ is nonnegative.
3. For each real $x$ **such that** $f(x)=7,$ we have that $2<x<9.$
4. Suppose that $n$ is an integer **such that** $5|(n + 2).$
5. There exists a real $c$ **such that** $f(c)=0.$

---

In the OP's given examples, ‘such that’ is correct whereas ‘so that’ is wrong.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/16887/172946

Comment: @C.F.G Thanks; many of the Answers on that page are (seductive but) inaccurate to outright wrong. $\quad$ For example, one Answer there distinguishes the two phrases by claiming that 'such that' expresses consequence, but in fact this property is a defining feature of '*so that*'! Another Answer there says that 'such that' is a description of "how", but this isn't exactly true if you consider my four examples.