# Is this star-shaped graph planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[image]

I've been given that the above graph is planar, but I can't for the life of me redraw it such that none of the edges intersect: the last(10th) edge I draw in on my rough paper always produces an intersection. Would someone prove or disprove the planarity of this graph?

Comment: This question reminds me of the game planarity.  You should play it, then this challenge would seem easy :)
http://www.planarity.net/

Comment: @ryang Please do not make trivial edits on old questions. That pushes them to the head of the active question queue, which wastes time for folks like me who track active questions.

Comment: [disappearing] @EthanBolker Sure. P.S. I made the edit while writing up ["So That" vs. "Such That"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4508819/21813).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [wheel graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph) $W_6$:

[image: wheel graphs]

(taken from Wikipedia)

Comment: (I was trying to get the OP to come up with this by themselves.)

Comment: @TaraB Your answer has reinforced what I had crucially forgotten: that edges are allowed to "cut through" one another when "rearranging" a graph to find an appropriate isomorphism, and that I don't have to restrict myself to the 2-d plane when doing so. Not sure if I'm making sense but thank you, Colin and Tara!

Comment: @Ryan:  No problem!  I'm glad it helped.  Graph isomorphism isn't nearly as complicated as you were making it! =]

Comment: Note that you don't even have enough information to say whether two edges 'cut through' each other when you rearrange, since the drawing of a graph doesn't carry information about which edge is 'on top'.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

Then just move the six in the center.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration.

Answer (score 2):

It is planar.  Try numbering the five outer vertices and then rearranging them so that you still have the same edges, but now none of them cross.  (Hint: if you number them 1 to 5 clockwise from the top, then since there is an edge between 1 and 3, it'd probably help to move 3 to the current position of 2.)

Answer (score 2):

A finite graph is planar iff it doesn't contain either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as a minor. It's easy to eliminate both possibilities for this graph, so it is planar.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks; has this got to do with subdividing and/or contracting graphs? If so, could please provide some elaboration? I'm struggling to understand these related ideas, and would much appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: This is a theorem which you may see later on in a graph theory course.  If you haven't seen it yet, I wouldn't worry about it too much for now, though it's very nice.  In this particular case I think it's much easier to show the graph is planar by exhibiting a planar embedding than by showing it has no $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ minor!

Comment: So what Peter said is indeed related to Kuratowski's Thm? Well, I've already seen it in the course, but the coverage was very patchy. Help?

Comment: @Ryan, what I stated is (a slight misquote of - I'll correct it) Wagner's theorem, but it's closely related to Kuratowski's theorem.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Time to do some googling.